# Xamarin form - How to customize picket control

Tags: xamarin, picker, custom-renderer

I am using latest xamarin build 4.5 and trying to apply picker control with following facilities..

1. Binding option- I could not see ItemsSource property in latest xamarin release. I have used following code to bind picker control in c#

   _pcPicker = this.FindByName("pcPicker");

   foreach (var item in ParentCategory)
    {
       _pcPicker.Items.Add(item.Name);
    }

   **I need to bind category id also along with category name...please guide me how to bind and get id of selected category.**

I could not follow this link for bindable picker - https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-for-xamarin-forms/ ... example given is not complete.

2. I need add to additional link (Add New category..) at the end of the picker list just as shown in below image.

**Please guide me how to customize picker control to achieve these two requirement-**

[image]

Thanks,

@Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This nuget package is great and will allow you to achieve what you want.

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

It allows you to create a pop up of any type of page. So for your picker, you could create a view that has a StackPanel, that has a ListView (so you can bind your ItemSource) and then 2 buttons New Category, Edit Category.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i tried creating a popup showing list of category using listview. Popup is gread but i need a picker kind of functionality like selecting any item from listview showing in popup, popup will go away and selected item will be shown in parent page.

Comment: @paulsim 100% you can use this plugin to create a picker style control. I'm about to head out now, but when I get back I'll post a sample of a picker control that I created that uses an ItemSource and dismisses the popup on selection whilst firing an itemselected event.

Comment: I have done this using "messaging center". How same thing can be done in xamarin native(android) as as per my knowledge " messaging center" is not available for xamarin native. Would you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577529/xamarin-android-update-ui-control-of-one-activity-from-another-activity