# Xamarin Android - Update UI control of one activity from another activity

Tags: c#, android-activity, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I have one Fragment "AddNewIncomeFragment " with a TextView("@+id/lblAccountHead"). On click on textview it starts a new activity "AccountHeadListActivit" which shows a list of existing Account Head. On selection of account head from "AccountHeadListActivity" i want to update "lblAccountHead" of first activity with selected account name, other values need to be intact.

Earlier i did it using "messaging center" for xamarin form. Now i trying to do the same in xamarin native(android).

*****UPDATED WITH FIRST SOLUTION APPLIED****

**Click event in AddNewIncomeFragment which start account head activity:**

```
  public void onAccounyHeadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               var intend = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(AccountHeadListActivity));
        //this.StartActivity(intend);
        this.StartActivityForResult(intend, 1000);
        }
```

**ListView Selection event of Account head activity**

```
void OnSelection (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

                     var result = new Intent();
        result.PutExtra("name", "Salary Account");
        result.PutExtra("id", 2);
        SetResult(Result.Ok, result);
       Finish();
        }
```

On closing this activity i want to update textview of previous activity with selected account head name/id. Please share what option we have to do this in xamarin andriod, should use StartActivityForResult,Local Notifications or any best approach.

---

**I have implemented above solution and it is working fine. But the issue is- 2nd activity "AccountHeadList" contains an add new account link which start a new activity "AddNewAccount"- Now if user create a new account and save it then this activity need to be closed and 1st activity need to updated with newly created account name. So basically "StartActivityForResult" failed when it involves three activity and need to updated 1st activity from 3rd activity- Please suggest.**

---

Thanks,

@Paul

Comment: instead of using finish() close the third activity, you can just start the first activity and pass the data you need through a bundle in an intent, then in your oncreate() method you can get data from the bundle if it exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To receive a result, call 
`startActivityForResult()` instead of startActivity()

then in your second activity, call the `setResult(result)` method to set the result before you finish the activity `finish()` after that in your original activity you can override the method

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent     data) {
      // set the text view with the data from the result
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggested solution is working fine(i have updated the question with applied solution). But problem arises when it requires to update first activity from third activity, Please refer to updated question for details.

Comment: Does you third activity open you first activity directly or it has to go through the second activity?

Comment: First activity open second activity which is list of items, if required item is not available then "add new button" in 2nd activity open 3rd activity to add new item. Once item is added that new item is shown in first activity.

Comment: ok... one thing you have to know about activities is that you should never rely on them that they would be available anytime you need them, because they could be closed at anytime. So let me ask, are you saving the data in any database of preference file?